# Error processing WSDL document

Tags: web-services, apache, webservice-client

I've got a code and I'm trying to run it. I think it uses Apache but I ave no idea how that works.
There's no error in the code, but when I run it, I get the following error.
Is it something wrong I've done or from the web service?

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.apache.axis.client.Service.initService(Service.java:250)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Service.<init>(Service.java:204)
    at msg.soa.oneits.net.definitions.OneitsServiceLocator.<init>(OneitsServiceLocator.java:21)
    at MainLoopDet.main(MainLoopDet.java:27)
```

Comment: May be you haven't published the service on the IP/Port you are trying to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your endpoint. Connection timeout is generally seen if IP/Port are not configured properly. Also check if your webservice is up and running by sending a request like `http://<IP>:port/context/<yourservicepath>?wsdl`